# Prolog print board list of list

Tags: list, prolog, printf

I've the next board:

```
board :- ([[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],[-,-,-,-,-,-,-],[-,-,-,-,-,-,-]]).
```

where each column represents a sublist.

My codec is:

```
printBoard(T) :-  write('  A B C D E F G'), nl, printLine(T,6).
printLine(_, 0).
printLine([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7], N) :- write(N), ith(N,P1,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P2,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P3,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P4,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P5,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P6,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                                ith(N,P7,C), imp(C), write(' '),
                                    nl, J is N -1, printLine([P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7],J),!.
```

Where

```
imp(o):- write(o).
imp(x):- write(x).
imp(-):- write(-).

% ith(I,L,Z) := Z is the Ith element of list L
%            := on L = emptylist returns a space

 ith(_,[],' ').
 ith(1,[Y|_],Z) :- Y=Z.
 ith(I,[_|W],Z) :- J is I-1, ith(J,W,Z).
```

But no found, prolog says no , and only paints '  A B C D E F G'. Because? 
which is the error? Thank's

This is my input:

```
 printBoard([[a,-,-,-,-,-,-],[b,-,-,-,-,-,-],[c,-,-,-,-,-,-],[d,-,-,-,-,-,-],[e,-,-,-,-,-,-],[f,-,-,-,-,-,-]]).
```

This is my output actualy
[image]

But I want you out:

```
 A  B  C  D  E  F  G
 a  b  c  d  e  f  g
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
 -  -  -  -  -  -  -
```

in the end I 've done it this way

```
printBoard(T)  :- write('  A B C D E F G'), nl, printLine(T).
printLine([[],[],[],[],[],[],[]]).
rintLine([[P1|P1X],[P2|P2X],[P3|P3X],[P4|P4X],[P5|P5X],[P6|P6X],[P7|P7X]]) :-
    imp(P1), write(' '),
    imp(P2), write(' '),
    imp(P3), write(' '),
    imp(P4), write(' '),
    imp(P5), write(' '),
    imp(P6), write(' '),
    imp(P7), write(' '), nl, J is N -1,     printLine([P1X,P2X,P3X,P4X,P5X,P6X,P7X],J),!.
```

Comment: What query did you enter and what was the actual message or output? And what was the specific desired output? Note that Prolog already has a predicates `nth0/3` and `nth1/3` so you don't need `ith/3`.

Comment: Your call to `printLine/2` fails because `printLine/2` requires that the first argument be a list of 7 elements, but you are passing a list of 6 elements.

Comment: You are right. thank's